# Как организовать базу данных для нескольких серверов

Tags: sqlite3

Я пишу своего дискорд бота на js. Для хранения данных использую sqlite3. Я хочу создать базу данных, которая будет индивидуальна для каждого сервера. Я знаю как создать базу данных для одного сервера (например, если у юзера на сервере X будет 10 монет, то и на любых других серверах у него тоже будет 10 монет), а как организовать бд так, чтобы данные одного человека на разных серверах могли быть разными?

Comment: Просто к идентификатору человека в базе добавить ещё какой-нибудь идентификатор сервера, наверное?

Comment: @andreymal, можно, допустим я добавляю ему идентификатор сервера, если человек на двух серверах, добавляю два идентификатора, а как разделять информацию пользователя на двух серверах?

Comment: Очевидно, разделять по идентификатору сервера. Кажется, я не очень понимаю вашей проблемы

Comment: @andreymal, либо вы уже предложили мне правильный выход, а я не понимаю) Вообщем, нужно, чтобы у пользователя на разных серверах были индивидуальные данные, я просто не понимаю, как организовать бд

Comment: либо я просто не знаю как объединять группу строк из второго столбца таблицы (например юзеров) под одну строку первого столбца (например айди сервера)

Comment: Можно конечно для одной строки с id сервера добавлять во второй столбец для него массив с данными пользователей, но это кажется слишком громоздко, нет ли варианта поизящнее?

Comment: создайте отдельную таблицу с тремя столбцами: идентификатор пользователя, идентификатор сервера, количество монет. // доп. чтение: [нормализация данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)